# How to avoid global screen variable?

Tags: screen, global, pygame

This question is being asked in the context of Pygame, but I have wondered about a good solution for any sort of graphics programming.

So, whenever you write a graphics program there is usually a screen variable holding the data for the screen being displayed. All the examples I have seen make this variable global so that all other objects have easy access too it such as in the simple example below.

```
import pygame

background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, (x, y), size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colour = (0, 0, 255)
        self.thickness = 1

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size, self.thickness)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 2')
screen.fill(background_colour)

my_first_particle = Particle((150, 50), 15)
my_first_particle.display()

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

My question is whether there is a better way of doing this so that the screen isn't global. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is `display.get_surface()`:

```
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, (x, y), size):
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific problem with having this global ?
Anyway you could add the display surface as an argument for the **init**() function of your objects, and render to this argument.

Maybe it's just my own way of using pygame, but I mostly use sprites, and render them through a renderer's clear() and draw() functions. Those functions ask for a surface (probably screen) variable, so that my screen isn't global (if I remember correctly).